# Positioning UIScrollView scrollIndicatorInsets to edges, no spacing?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, scrollbar

How does the ScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets actually work ?

If you set all insets to 0 as default, and you do some debugging you will actually find that the scrollbar isn't exactly near the bottom or right edges by default as it should be.

```
ScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

[image: Example]

As you can see, there is some extra spacing between the scrollbar and the scroll view edges.

**Is there any way that I can place the scrollbar bottom left corner exactly at the bottom left corner of the view programatically ?** I don't want to hardcode anything, I want it to work on any scrollview size and screen.

What do the insets actually specify (yes, I know they specify a rectangle for the scrollbar) ? Is there a default spacing-to-edge that iOS uses for the scrollbar and I have to take that into consideration ? Is there glow on the scrollbar's layer view, hence the spacing ?

**EDIT:**

I solved this using the non-convential approach by accessing the UIView from the scrollbar itself (subviews.last), and using the smallest size (which is the thickness).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick inspection shows the Scroll Indicators with Insets set to `UIEdgeInsetsZero` (the default) places them 3-pts from the edges.

You can try using:

```
theScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: -3, left: -3, bottom: -3, right: -3)
```

which *should* align the horizontal indicator flush to the bottom, and flush with the left and right edges, and the vertical indicator flush to the right, and flush with the top and bottom edges.

You *might* want to get the frame(s) first though, as it's possible it varies between devices / sizes / iOS versions.

**Edit:**

A couple clarifying notes...

The `scroll indicators` are image views. You can find them by inspecting the scroll view's subviews (code or with Debug View Hierarchy).

The default insets (of Zero) put those image views 3-pts from the edge of the scroll view's frame.

With a `300 x 500` scroll view, the origin of the vertical indicator is:

```
  x:294.5 y:3.0   with a width of 2.5
  294.5 + 2.5 == 297
  // 3-pts from the right edge, 3-pts from the top
```

and the origin of the horizontal indicator is:

```
  x:3.0 y:494.5   with a height of 2.5
  494.5 + 2.5 == 497
  // 3-pts from the left edge, 3-pts from the bottom
```

So, using:

```
.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: -3, left: -3, bottom: -3, right: -3)
```

moves the origins to

```
  // vertical
  x:297.5 y:0.0   with a width of 2.5
  297.5 + 2.5 == 300
  // flush to top and right edges

  // horizontal
  x:0.0 y:497.5   with a height of 2.5
  497.5 + 2.5 == 500
  // flush to left and bottom edges
```

I suppose it's *possible* that could change in the future. As fewer and fewer people use devices with small screens, Apple *could* change the width/height to 3 or 3.5 or whatever, and *could* change the default inset from 3 to something else. Which is why I said you might want to get the frames to get the proper inset values, rather than hard-coding them to `3`.

Curiously, though, until the indicator frames have been drawn to the screen - either by flashing them or actually scrolling the content - their frames are set to 7-pts in height (for the vertical indicator) and 7-pts width (for the horizontal), and positioned at the bottom-right corner.

So, with the `500 x 300` scroll view frame, the indicator frames are initially:

```
  // vertical
  x:294.5 y:490.0 w:2.5 h:7.0
  // horizontal
  x:290.0 y:494.5 w:7.0 h:2.5
```

That still tells you they are 3-pts from the edges, but it's not quite as clear... and again, no guarantee that won't change in the future.

If you really want sure the indicators will go where you want them, your best bet may be to use custom views instead of the built-in indicators.

Comment: What do you mean by "You might want to get the frame(s) first though, as it's possible it varies between devices / sizes / iOS versions." I tried everything without hardcoded values, and result is not consistent within devices and orientations, I even tried accessing the scrollbar view and take it's size, but not consistent.

Comment: Yeah, the 7 buggy part I figured out also from the debugger. Also the frame sizes are 0 until the scrollbar is actually visible. I will give 1 more shot, by taking the scrollbar view frame sizes after calling flashIndicators or inside didScroll. I was also a bit confused before you replied regarding the scrollbar anchor point... but then I figured out that every edge is anchored to the superview's corresponding edges actually. This makes sense now, and theoretically it should work, I will try one more time and reply back with the results. Thank you.

Comment: Just so you know what I'm trying to achieve is that I want to have a background line behind the scrollbar. So I need to somehow position the scrollbar to scroll along a line (UIImageView) and that's why I kinda need the absolute positions so the scrollbar would be centered on my line, in fact the other way around, my image line should be center on the scrollbar.